# How to declare a sorted set of array of ints in Scala?

Tags: scala, sortedset

I have tried all of the following for scala.collection.mutable.SortedSet:

```
var s = SortedSet[Array[Int]]
var s = SortedSet[Array[Int]]()
var s = new SortedSet[Array[Int]]
var s = new SortedSet[Array[Int]]()
var s = SortedSet[Array]
var s = SortedSet[Array]()
var s = new SortedSet[Array]()
```

I don't know why it has to be so hard to just declare this stuff in Scala. All I want is a sorted set of Int-arrays.

Comment: Putting mutable objects like `Array` into a set (or using them as keys for a map) makes it really easy to break correctness—you can end up with duplicate values, values out of order, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SortedSet` is not a "default" collection, therefore not defined in `Predef`.

First import it then it should work:

```
import scala.collection.SortedSet
val s = SortedSet[Array[Int]]()
```

Next to this you need an implicit ordering defined:

```
implicit val arrayOrdering = new Ordering[Array[Int]] {
   override def compare(x: Array[Int], y: Array[Int]): Int = ???
     // Implement whatever you mean by one array is greater than the other array
}
```

Also be careful with `Array`-s as that is a Java array, so it does not have the `equals` and `hashcode` methods overridden and does not look at value equality, but rather reference equality.

Comment: What is the implicit ordering bit? How it defines order among arrays? Like I want it to look like [(3,5), (3,7), (3,10), (6,2), (6,7), ... sorted by first element

Comment: Also what does it mean for a compare to return an int?

Comment: If those are your actual values then use a Tuple instead of an Array. It would be easier: `SortedSet[(Int, Int)]`. That would have the `Ordering` defined already. If you need the array then I will leave it up to you to figure out how to compare two arrays the way you want it.

Comment: The `compare` `Int` is from Java where `-1 = Before`, `0 = Equal`, `1 = After` and you have to return with one of these when you compare `x` with `y`

Comment: Tuple should work fine but how would I even know that this was the correct solution? How am I supposed to know that tuples have ordering defined and arrays don't?

Comment: Experience with Scala :) Tuple is a language feature that is supported throughout Scala, while Array can have many differing values, lengths, types, etc.

Comment: Also, arrays are mutable. So a sort order on them can only be done with the current values., Which makes things like sortedsets difficult (they'd have to sort on every access, just in case the contents had changed). So a  predefined ordering for arrays is likely to mislead/fail, so there isn't one.